# GmsClient error in Flutter android application

Tags: android, flutter

Out of nowhere, I've started to get the following errors in the Console window when debugging my Flutter android application:

`E/GmsClient( 4521): unable to connect to service: com.google.android.location.internal.GoogleLocationManagerService.START on com.google.android.gms E/GmsClient( 4521): unable to connect to service: com.google.android.gms.safetynet.service.START on com.google.android.gms`

The applicacion uses Google maps (through flutter_google_maps component) and a Firebase RT database. It was working normally this morning. In the afternoon, it shows that message and stays in an infinite loop when trying to query the Firebase RT database.

The error is observed in both, the emulator and the real device.

Any ideas?